# Physically replace javascript variable in config file

Tags: javascript, variables

I am quite new to javascript and recently faced an issue that I don't know how to solve. I basically want to develop a way to be able to reach out to registered users to display a message on their account when needed.

I thought about creating a notifications.js file in my config folder, containing an array of the following type:

```
var notifications = [{
    'message': 'First message',
    'user': 'First user to contact'
}, {
    'message': 'Another message',
    'user': 'Another user to contact'
}]
```

I could then write the messages in these files when needed, instead of having to go through my database to do it (I find it easier this way for several reasons, such as the possibility to use directly the internationalization plugin I use, for example). I then export this variable in order to use it where needed.

However, when the message gets displayed, I would like to erase it so that it only appears once. With the Vue framework, I wrote a small function able to do it, erasing correctly the right index of the notifications array but these changes are obviously not kept in the notifications.js file and when the page is reloaded, the message appears again.

Is there any way to "physically overwrite" the variable in that file, modifying it directly in the config file? I thought about using the localStorage instead but it does not seem to be a good solution since once the message has been displayed once, I don't want the user to see it again, even if he changes browser.

Hope I explained myself clearly, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

After some additional research, it seems that we I wanted to do simply [cannot be done](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/edit-json-file-from-component/30055/2). If someone else runs into the same issue, I ended up serving my notifications from a json file from my server, and even thought this is more complicated than I thought, it seems to be working just fine. Cheers!